# Control Visibility of Toolbar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I contributed to the default menu and toolbar, but now want to make some parts of the menus invisible for some users.

In menus, this works:

```
 <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      <menu id="menu.project" label="%menu.project">
           <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                <test property="currentUser.notUserGroup" value="ADMINISTRATOR" />
           </visibleWhen>
      </menu>
 </menuContribution>
```

For toolbars the editor of the *plugin.xml* lets me choose the same structure:

```
 <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
      <toolbar id="toolbar.project">
           <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
                <test property="currentUser.notUserGroup" value="ADMINISTRATOR" />
           </visibleWhen>
      </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
```

However, that does not work. The items contributed to `toolbar.project` are still visible.

How do I control the visibility of a toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue: see [Eclipse bug 201589](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201589)

There is a [patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=153008) attached to the bug which unfortunately is incomplete and very old (pre Eclipse 4.x).